# I was perusing glibc when I came across the socket code, can someone explain what is going on?

Tags: c, glibc

Here is the source I was browsing: [glibc source](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=socket;h=8217353b094378659dae035c0619f6495172523c;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f). My particular question arises from this particular set of functions: [socket library](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=socket;h=8217353b094378659dae035c0619f6495172523c;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f).

For example(most of the functions are set up this way) `socket/bind.c`'s source is:

```
  19 #include <errno.h>
  20 #include <sys/socket.h>
  21 
  22 /* Give the socket FD the local address ADDR (which is LEN bytes long).  */
  23 int
  24 __bind (fd, addr, len)
  25      int fd;
  26      __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG addr;
  27      socklen_t len;
  28 {
  29   __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  30   return -1;
  31 }
  32 
  33 weak_alias (__bind, bind)
  34 
  35 stub_warning (bind)
  36 #include <stub-tag.h>
```

I admit I didn't spend a lot of time, but where exactly is the code for the actual function and what is going on? Is this a well used paradigm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__bind` function is a [stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub): it's a function that looks externally like the real thing (same prototype) but does not perform the requisite function.

The [`weak_alias`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=include/libc-symbols.h;h=252141eb0111269d721c501b1bcac0cd94c3305a;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f#l110) macro tells the linker that `bind` is to be a weak alias for `__bind`. That is, this definition of `bind` is a [weak symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol). If there is no other definition of a symbol called `bind`, this definition stands; if there is another (non-weak) definition of `bind` then that non-weak definition stands and the weak definition is ignored. A weak alias is a weak symbol that is an alias of another symbol (as opposed to having a definition in its own right). The [`stub_warning`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=include/libc-symbols.h;h=252141eb0111269d721c501b1bcac0cd94c3305a;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f#l280) macro causes the linker to emit a warning if that weak alias is used.

The real implementation of `bind` depends on the operating system that Glibc is compiled for. On [Hurd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Hurd), it is defined in [`sysdeps/mach/hurd/bind.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/mach/hurd/bind.c;h=a42b78ac07c7a72041f07650860567b6e9547a30;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f). On Linux, `bind` is a system call: there is no C code for it in the Glibc source, only assembly code. `bind` is provided in [`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bind.S`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bind.S;h=7719ad0be8bb6c2ad6c2722393b44f148a19de1c;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f) which reuses the architecture-dependent definition of `socket` in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/**/socket.S` or `ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/*/socket.S`. Those definitions are all thin wrappers around the underlying system call, taking care to copy the argument and the return values into the proper registers.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking at the general bind() implementation which ... just tells you that bind() is not implementet (It just returns an error and sets errno to ENOSYS - syscall not implemented.).

Many platform dependent system calls  in glibc work this way - there's a default implementation that just returns an error, and each platform/architector have to provide an implementation of the system call if one exists.

Look in e.g. ./sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/socket.S for the linux x86 implementation.

Ofcourse, socket() is just a system call, so the actual implementation is in the kernel. Glibc just provides a C wrapper to call it.

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed to know. I had a hunch that this was a sort of skeleton, but I had no idea where else to look to find the implementation. Your answer was concise, quick, and helpful. I was meaning to see what the wrapper for socket() was and your tips will help me continue the search!